# Username length restriction in different MySQL environments

Tags: mysql, users

I am setting up a project to my local environment and at its initial script are some SQL commands for creating the database:

- `create database 'db-name' default character set utf8;`

and to `grant` privileges for the user account:

- `grant select, insert, update, delete, create, drop, index, alter on 'db-name'.* to 'user-name-too-long-for-user-name'@'localhost' identified by 'user-name-pass'`

When I am trying to run the `grant` command I get this:

- `ERROR 1470 (HY000): String 'user-name-to-long-for-user-name' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)`

and I can't understand why is this happening whereas this same script has successfully run to another environment before it comes to mine.

The server version I am using is *5.6.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)*.

Is this situation related to a certain MySQL version or something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The maximum length for a user name in MySQL does depend on the version, [as stated in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-names.html):

> MySQL user names can be up to 32 characters long (16 characters before MySQL 5.7.8).

Answer (score -1):

Working at 10.7.3-MariaDB

```
USE mysql;
ALTER TABLE db CHANGE User User CHAR(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE User User CHAR(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE columns_priv CHANGE User User CHAR(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE procs_priv CHANGE User User CHAR(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE proxies_priv CHANGE User User CHAR(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE tables_priv CHANGE User User CHAR(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

restart mysql